# JQuery hide closest with classname not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select a parent (with a specific class name) of an element of containing a certain attribute.

Here's how the HTML file looks like

```
<li class="parentClass...">
  <div class="...">
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        <h3 class="...">
          <a title="...">
        <div class="...">
          <a href="/user/userName"...></a>
```

Here's my JQuery (in a JS file)

```
$("a[href~='/user/userName']").closest("li[class^='parentClass']").hide()
```

So when I run this nothing happens. 
If I console.log() the query it prints out an

`[pevObject: r.fn.init(0)]`

However if I run the command from the console in Chrome
I get an error:

`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).closest(...).hide is not a function`

To save you some time, yes when I remove the hide() function run it from the console it does print an element (which I can manually hide using chrome)

EDIT: fixed miss matched quotes

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, fixed it, didn't copy it properly

Comment: In which your code should be working absolutely fine. Are you sure the HTML you've shown matches exactly what's in your page?

Comment: Well I don't get any error but the element doesn't hide at all

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $("a[href~='/user/userName']").closest(".parentClass").toggle()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="parentClass">
  <div class="...">
    <div class="...">
      <div class="...">
        <h3 class="...">
          <a title="...">
        <div class="...">
          <a href="/user/userName">link</a>
        </div>
        </a>
        </h3>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </li>
<button>Toggle</button>
```